# Can't Connect to Database from Java program

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I installed MySQL database & JDBC. I created a database called feedback through MySQL command line client, and I want to access that database through a java program.

Here is the commands I used on MySQL command line client create the database.

```
create database feedback;
use feedback; 
CREATE USER sqluser IDENTIFIED BY 'sqluserpw'; 

grant usage on *.* to sqluser@localhost identified by 'sqluserpw'; 
grant all privileges on feedback.* to sqluser@localhost; 
CREATE TABLE COMMENTS (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
MYUSER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO COMMENTS values (default, 'lars');
```

Then, the code in Java:

```
package de.vogella.mysql.first;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MYSQLACCESS {
private Connection connect = null;
  private Statement statement = null;
  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  private ResultSet resultSet = null;


  public void readDataBase() throws Exception {

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Before try" );
      try {
      // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // Setup the connection with the DB
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1" );

      connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");


      // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();
      // Result set get the result of the SQL query
      resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
    //  writeResultSet(resultSet);

      String my_user = resultSet.getString("MYUSER");
      System.out.println(my_user);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, my_user );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
      } 

    }
  }
```

The Main Class:

```
package de.vogella.mysql.first;
import de.vogella.mysql.first.MYSQLACCESS;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
MYSQLACCESS first_access = new MYSQLACCESS();
first_access.readDataBase();
}

}
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:              
 Access denied for user 'sqluser'@'localhost' to database 'feedback'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at de.vogella.mysql.first.MYSQLACCESS.readDataBase(MYSQLACCESS.java:30)
at de.vogella.mysql.first.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

I am following the tutorial in the following [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Any help?

Comment: make sure sqluser@localhost has privileges to access the database feedback

Comment: check the first code block i wrote, that is how i created the database, is there anything missing ?

Comment: Refer to: (When Privilege Changes Take Effect)[ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-changes.html ]

Comment: @Ravinder take away the ] from your url buddy

Comment: @яша Many a times I found a bug in *comments* editing tool implementation.

Comment: `sqluser@localhost` has access to feedback objects, but it does not have `connect` privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user `sqluser` does not have the privileges to access database `feedback` on the `localhost`.

Use the [mysql command line tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) and [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) the privileges to the user.

**Do not forget to [flush privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html)**

Answer (score 1):

usually when having this exception:

> Access denied for user 'sqluser'@'localhost' to database 'feedback'

means that this user don't have enough privileges to access the Database, what I would suggest you to do is to go to your SQL shell and write this command:

```
show grants;
```

it would show you which users has access to the Database and with their level of privilege

if this user don't seem to have the necessary privilege to access the DB you can grant it to him by writing this query in your SQL Shell

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sqluser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Good Luck;

Comment: I know that but I guess he is in the test state